# I can't bind the arrow key events

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, button

I currently have a next slice and previous slice button that can be clicked to move through the images. I would also like the keyboard left and right arrows to allow the user to go through the previous and next slices. So there should be two ways to go through the images. I am unable to get the keyboard click work within `prev_image` and `next_image`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)  # python3 style
    
        self.master.title("Slideshow")

        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        top_frame.pack()
    
        image_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        image_frame.pack()

        previous_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Previous Slice", command=self.prev_image)
        previous_button.pack(side="left")

        next_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="  Next Slice  ", command=self.next_image)
        next_button.pack(side="left")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(image_frame, bg='red')
        self.canvas.pack()
    
        self.canvas.bind('<Left>', self.prev_image)
        self.canvas.bind('<Right>', self.next_image)
        self.canvas.focus_set()

        self.master.bind('<Left>', self.prev_image)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', self.next_image)
    
    def prev_image(self, event=None):
        print('prev_image')
        if event:
            print('even:', event)

    def next_image(self, event=None):
        print('next_image')
        if event:
            print('even:', event)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: you have to bind only once. And maybe use `self.master.bind()` instead of `self.canvas.bind()`. Or it may need to set `focus()` on `canvas`. OR first create `root = tk.Tk()` and then use `root.bind()`

Comment: when I remove the both of the second self.canvas.bind's and change the first ones to self.master.bind(), I get the error saying "next_image() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: maybe first use `print()` in functions to see if they are executed. Maybe it runs these functions but you may have different problem - like `bug` in `PhotoImage`

Comment: it would be simpler if you create minimal working code which we could simply copy and test. Current code has missing `Canvas`, `load_image`, `image_set_rows`, `current_image_index`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the code for a *runnable* [mre] and I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: BTW: `command=` expects function which doesn't get arguments `def prev_image(self)` but `bind` expects function which get one argument - `def prev_image(self, event)` to send `event` to this function - so you can check what key was clicked. To use the same function in `command` and `bind` you may use `event=None` - `def prev_image(self, event=None)`

Comment: Have you tried explicitly giving the keyboard focus to the canvas? By default it doesn't accept keyboard events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `focus` on `canvas` to get keys in `canvas`

```
        self.canvas.bind('<Left>', self.prev_image)
        self.canvas.bind('<Right>', self.next_image)
        self.canvas.focus_set()
```

or you may bind keys to master window

```
        self.master.bind('<Left>', self.prev_image)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', self.next_image)
```

Second version may be better because `canvas` may lose `focus` - ie. when you use key `tab` to jump from widget to widget.

---

Other problem.

`command=` needs function which doesn't get arguments but `bind()` needs function which get one argument - because it sends information about event (ie. pressed key, mouse position, etc.)

To use the same function in `command=` and `bind()` you need argument with default value - ie. `even=None`

```
    def prev_image(self, event=None):
        # ... code ...

    def next_image(self, event=None):
        # ... code ...
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)  # python3 style
        
        self.master.title("Slideshow")

        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        top_frame.pack()
        
        image_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        image_frame.pack()
    
        previous_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Previous Slice", command=self.prev_image)
        previous_button.pack(side="left")

        next_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="  Next Slice  ", command=self.next_image)
        next_button.pack(side="left")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(image_frame, bg='red')
        self.canvas.pack()
        
        #self.canvas.bind('<Left>', self.prev_image)
        #self.canvas.bind('<Right>', self.next_image)
        #self.canvas.focus_set()

        self.master.bind('<Left>', self.prev_image)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', self.next_image)
        
    def prev_image(self, event=None):
        print('prev_image')
        self.canvas['bg'] = 'blue'
        if event:
            print('even:', event)

    def next_image(self, event=None):
        print('next_image')
        self.canvas['bg'] = 'green'
        if event:
            print('even:', event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.pack()
    app.mainloop()
    
    #root = tk.Tk()
    #app = App(root)
    #app.pack()
    #root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you!! The minimal working example with your suggestions on adding the self.canvas.focus_set() works for next image if I press the next arrow key but for previous image, it gives me the same "prev_image() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" error

Comment: my example works without problem. You have to use `event=None` in both functions `next_image` and `previous_image`

Comment: Got it to work, thank you!!